# True or false: a chain of at most countable sets has an at most countable union.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Is the following statement true or false?

> Let $\{A_i,\ i\in I\}$ be a family of at most countable sets. Suppose the family is totally ordered under set inclusion, i.e. $\forall i\in I,\ j\in I$, either $A_i\subset A_j$ or conversely. Then $\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$ is also at most countable.

I had this problem when I was trying to prove something else using Zorn's lemma. Although my original problem had a simpler solution, I am now more interested in this new question I came up with, so I won't post my original problem as it is sort of irrelevant.

The difficulty is that $I$ may not be a countable index set. Yet, I was unable to find a counterexample or a proof off the top of my head. Any ideas?

Comment: The set of roots of quadratic integer polynomials is countable. So is the set of roots of cubic integer polynomials and so forth; I strongly suspect their union over $n$ (maximal degree of integer polynomial) *isn't*. EDIT: Actually they are. Apparently they are called 'Algebraic numbers'.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I mean that each $A_i$ is at most countable, but there could be uncountably many sets $A_i$. I added a pair of braces, if that helps...

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof No, the set of algebraic numbers is countable

Comment: @MatthewDaly But we need not have polynomials with algebraic coefficients.

Comment: @saulspatz Note that the family needs to be totally ordered. Your example does not satisfy this condition.

Comment: OK, and if we start with some real number, than add another real number to get another set and always add a real number and $I$ is uncountable , what then ?

Comment: Try explicitly doing that, @Peter. It isn't that evident, since there exists no bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$. In particular, there is no guarantee that the $i-$th set is countable.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof If this does not work, can we have an uncountable family with the desired property then ?

Comment: @Peter Just a thought, "add another number" is the same as expanding the index set by one element, which should lead to a countable index set.

Comment: @Peter Frankly I have no clue at this moment!

Comment: @Peter The thing is, exactly what is meant by "an uncountable number of steps", how do we walk such steps? Naturally, steps should be one after another.

Comment: I don't think this is possible.  Can't we take the index set to be the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$, and for $\sigma<\omega_1$, take $A_\sigma=\sigma$?  Then $\bigcup_{\sigma<\omega_1}A_\sigma=\omega_1$ which is uncountable.

Comment: @AlexanderGeldhof Yes, but each of them is countable, which is all that matters.

Comment: Similarly: Given a chain of finite sets, is its union necessarily finite?